# Calculating the potential of a uniformly charged spherical shell

Tags: electrostatics, potential

This question only really has to do with how to get the correct denominator in the integral.

The object in question is a uniformly charged sphere of radius $R$. I'm going to choose as my reference point a point on the $z$ axis. I do this because I think (although I'm not sure) that potential is measured in reference to a test charge located some distance away from it, and (at least given the symmetry of the sphere) it doesn't matter where I place it really, so let $\vec r = d \hat z$ for convenience.

I need a vector equation to parametrise the perimeter of the sphere.

$$\text{let} \ \vec r' = R\ (\cos \theta \ \hat x + \sin \theta \ \hat y)$$

Thus,

$$\vec r - \vec r' = -R\ (\cos \theta \ \hat x + \sin \theta \ \hat y) + d\hat z$$

However, apparently the distance is meant to be:

$$\sqrt{z^2 + R^2 - 2Rz \cos \theta'}$$

Where I am meant to apparently put primes over the theta. How do I get this from my expression?

Comment: your $\vec r'$ should have a $z$-component.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is better to work in spherical coordinates, where a point on your sphere is 
$$
\vec r'=\hat x R\sin\theta'\cos\phi+\hat y R\sin\theta'\sin\phi +
\hat z R\cos\theta'
$$
and your point on the axis is $\vec r=z\hat z$.
Then the length of the vector $\vec r'-\vec r$ is
$$
\vert \vec r'-\vec r\vert = \sqrt{(\vec r'-\vec r)\cdot (\vec r'-\vec r)}
$$
with 
\begin{align}
(\vec r'-\vec r)\cdot (\vec r'-\vec r)&= R^2 +z^2 -2 \vec r'\cdot \vec r\, ,\\
&= R^2 +z^2 -2 R z\cos\theta'\, . 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

You $\vec r'$ is a point in the x-y plane distance $R$ from the origin.

[image]

The distance is the length of the $z\,\hat z- R\,\hat r$ vector found using the cosine rule.